# In the sklearn RandomForestClassifier, is class_weight=None equivalent to class_weight="balanced_subsample"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

The wording in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) makes it seem like None and "balanced_subsample" are equivalent, but I want to make sure that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation clearly says that they are **not** equivalent:

`class_weight=None` - all classes are supposed to have weight one

`class_weight='balanced_subsample'` -  “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`.

The “balanced_subsample” mode is the same as “balanced” except that weights are computed based on the bootstrap sample for every tree grown.

Comment: Ah I see. I think what was confusing me was that the first line randomly breaks into a second line in the [documentation for class_weight](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), so I thought the second line was beginning a new sentence with "'balanced_subsample' or None"... Thank you for your response.